# Access container outside of constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, unity-container

With Unity, I can inject various controls/interfaces via constructor like following:

```
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeView_EmployeeListViewModel(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }
```

However, I need to access the specific control (let's say the one used in an example) outside of the constructor (I cannot edit constructor).

Is there a way, how to do it?

**EDIT**
more info - I have a DataForm, which allows users to do simple CRUD operations on their DataGrid (simple edit form). This control is from **Telerik inc.** and therefore it's commands class looks like following:

```
public class CustomDataFormCommandProvider : DataFormCommandProvider
{
    public CustomDataFormCommandProvider():base(null)
    {
    }
    protected override void MoveCurrentToNext()
    {
        if (this.DataForm != null)
        {
            this.DataForm.MoveCurrentToNext();
            this.DataForm.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

    protected override void MoveCurrentToPrevious()
    {
        if (this.DataForm != null)
        {
            this.DataForm.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
            this.DataForm.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

    protected override void CommitEdit()
    {
        if (this.DataForm != null && this.DataForm.ValidateItem())
        {
            this.DataForm.CommitEdit();
        }
    }

    protected override void CancelEdit()
    {
        if (this.DataForm != null)
        {
            this.DataForm.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

If by any means I change the constructor, commands stop working (therefore I cannot put my Interface into the constructor).

What I need to do, is under `CommitEdit`, except for updating the usercontrol, I also want to do a separate call, which would save particular user's changes under the database (my `IEmployeeRepository` takes care of all).

That's why I need to find a way, how to achieve it this 'proper' way. I can surely re-style the template of this control and rebind OK & Cancel buttons, but I don't believe that's the way to go.

**FINAL**

`ServiceLocator` did the job. Here is the code:

```
_employeeRepository = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEmployeeRepository>();
```

Comment: You can access `_employeeRepository` anywhere in your class. Or do you want a dependency injected, but not through the constructor? You could go for setter injection then. Use `[Dependency]` on a property to have it injected upon resolving.

Comment: What I do is, that I have a command provider for my Data Form (with pre-defined constructor I cannot change) and when Submit button has been clicked, I need to pass the parameters to the specific control (I need to invoke command)

Comment: Can you bind the button to a command on the specific control? I think I don't fully understand what you're trying to do and what's the problem here. Can you put more code in the original question?

Comment: How is the `CustomDataFormCommandProvider` created? If it is resolved from your unity container, you can have the dependency to `IEmployeeRepository` injected in the constructor. If not, you can resolve it directly in `CommitEdit` using the `ServiceLocator`.

Comment: You are a star! ServiceLocator did the job. Make it an answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance` which can provide you with any dependency everywhere.

But be careful, as the dependency is pretty much hidden.